# Confusion about systematic error

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

Could someone please tell me why there is both a positive and negative sign with the systematic error? I thought it could only be either positive or negative.

A student uses a digital ammeter to measure a current. The reading of the ammeter is found to fluctuate between 1.98A and 2.02A.
The manufacturer of the ammeter states that any reading has a systematic uncertainty of ±1%.
Which value of current should be quoted by the student?

Comment: "I thought it could only be either positive or negative". Why would you think that?

Comment: because isnt systematic error consistent?? (Unlike random error, systematic errors tend to be consistently either positive or negative) Found this on the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either the manufacturer is using the word *systematic* wrong and really means random uncertainty (quite unlikely), or that statement means:

> Any ammeter we ship might have a systematic uncertainty of up to ±1%. Which one it is exactly will be random and vary from device to device.

In this case any given ammeter will consistently read up to 1% below or 1% above the actual current. Because this error is consistent between measurements for a certain device, it would be considered systematic.